# Azure CNAME / A record confusion

Tags: azure, dns, cname, a-records

I've set up my first site on Azure.  Let's call it 'mysite.org.uk'.  I've uploaded the files to Azure as a shared Azure website.  It's accessible at 'mysite.azurewebsites.net'.  Now I want to test it out by pointing a live subdomain to it, so basically I want it to resolve with the URL 'cloud.mysite.org.uk'.  I've read the documentation and it says that before I can add an A record to my domain to do this, I need to create a CNAME record.  The instructions it gives are:

> The DNS record for 'cloud.mysite.org.uk' that points to
>   'mysite.azurewebsites.net' could not be located. If you
>   want to configure an A record, you must first create a CNAME record
>   with your DNS provider for
>   'awverify.cloud.mysite.org.uk' that points to
>   'awverify.mysite.azurewebsites.net'. First allow the
>   resource record to propagate, and then create the A record.

Okay, so I've logged into the Plesk control panel of the current host (where the DNS is controlled) and added a CNAME record with 'host': awverify.www.mysite.org.uk. and 'value': awverify.mysite.azurewebsites.net.  I did this more than 24 hours ago so it should have propagated by now, but when I try to add the domain in the Azure portal it still tells me there's no verification CNAME record.  Similarly when I ping awverify.www.mysite.org.uk it doesn't resolve (surely it should if it's set up right, as it's a new record, so it shouldn't rely on DNS propagation time?).

To be on the safe side I've also created a CNAME with host: awverify.cloud.mysite.org.uk and value: awverify.mysite.azurewebsites.net and that too isn't working.  In fact when I add these CNAME records Plesk tells me:

> Unable to resolve the canonical name
>   awverify.mysite.azurewebsites.net.

Anyhow, I'm a little bit stuck.  I thought I'd followed the documentation pretty closely but obviously something isn't right.

If anyone has any pointers I'd be most grateful.

Thanks

Comment: With what provider have you registered your domain? Are you using that registrar's DNS servers or have you pointed your domain to other DNS servers? If so, what DNS provider did you point it at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must have been a propagation issue oddly, as 48 hours later it works when I add the domain to Azure.